# Generating a complete GNU Make recipe with Guile

Tags: gnu-make, guile

I am playing with the `$(guile ...)` support in GNU Make, but I'm having trouble generating a complete recipe from within Guile.

This traditional approach works as expected:

```
brazil:
<--tab-->@echo Ere I am J.H.
```

*(where `<--tab-->` is an ASCII tab character, as required)*

But when I try this supposed-equivalent:

`$(guile (format #f "brazil:~%~/@echo Ere I am J.H."))`

I am treated to the following error message when I run `make brazil`:

```
make: *** No rule to make target '@echo', needed by 'brazil'.  Stop.
```

I was under the impression that with `format`, `~%` encodes a newline, and `~/` encodes a tab character.  But based on the error message above, it seems like at least the newline is missing from the generated recipe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it this way, just like it won't work to have a `$(shell ...)` invocation define rules with multiple lines, and just like you can't use `define` / `endef` to create an entire multi-line rule then have it simply expanded with `$(MY_VAR)`.

The expansion of a single line (like a `$(guile ...)` operation) cannot expand to multiple lines of output: make uses a line-oriented parser and it's already parsed this line: any subsequent newlines will be treated as ordinary spaces (not newlines).

You need to use `$(eval ...)` to tell make to treat the output as an actual multi-line makefile snippet.  So you want:

```
$(eval $(guile (format #f "brazil:~%~/@echo Ere I am J.H.")))
```

You can also use this instead if you can put the recipe onto a single line:

```
$(guile (format #f "brazil: ; @echo Ere I am J.H."))
```

You can also put the recipe, if it must be multiline, into a variable and use:

```
$(guile (format #f "brazil: ; $(MY_RECIPE)"))
```